# Text Input Panel not showing up in WPF Pop Up

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, touch

In a touch enabled application we want to display a pop up for text input.
But for some reason the touch events won't invoke the tooltip for the touch input panel, which normally shows up when touching in a text input field.

Is there a way to invoke this tooltip programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try something like this:

```
private void OnTouchEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
    tt.Content = "My tooltip text";
    myComponentName.ToolTip=tt;
    tt.IsOpen = true;
}
```

If you want to be fancy, you can add a timer or something to make it go away after a little bit.